# Regular expression test is not consistent with returning values

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex:

```
var r = /^(\+?48)?\D*(?:(\d)\D*){9}/gi
```

Its purpose is to check whether a string contains (at least) 9 digits, mixed randomly with other non-digit characters. And I'm having this:

```
> r.test('    w3f23ev434r23f2e2323r23r48 12 345 62 89')
true
> r.test('    w3f23ev434r23f2e2323r23r48 12 345 62 89')
false
> r.test('    w3f23ev434r23f2e2323r23r48 12 345 62 89')
true
> r.test('    w3f23ev434r23f2e2323r23r48 12 345 62 89')
false
```

Why does this happen? Is a regex object instance mutable?

Comment: [Check out this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-regexp-with-global-flag-in-javascript-give-wrong-results)

Comment: Yes, and it happens because you used the `/g` flag. (Also, `/i` is useless there).

Comment: Still don't quite understand why `/g` works this way. As for `/i`, you're right, it was more out of habit rather that of practical value.

Comment: @RishatMuhametshin What did you think `/g` would do?

Comment: Okay, got the idea from [the Q&A mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-regexp-with-global-flag-in-javascript-give-wrong-results)!